# Sublime Text 3 deleted my folder under /Packages

Tags: package, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I added a plugin to Sublime Text 3 via github.

This creates a folder in my Packages folder. The problem:
when I restart sublime, it automatically deleted this folder.

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer by myself while browsing the sublime docs:

I have to add it into the `Packages/User` folder, this is the place where sublime will never delete something.

Comment: I had the same problem. Having put my package in `Packages/User` the commands defined in it aren't found by Sublime Text 3. Did you figure that part out, by any chance?

Comment: Where in the docs did you find this? This guide seems to say that you should put folders into the Packages directory: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/packages.html

Answer (score 3):

This seems to happen if you manually install a package instead of using Package Control. To fix, open your `Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings` file and add the package that is auto deleted.

Comment: additionally, make sure there is no `ignored_packages` entry for this package in `Preferences.sublime-settings` (same directory). This was required in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Basically this happens when you install a package manually. The package becomes **orphaned**, means there is a `package-metadata.json` file in the package but it is not installed in `Installed Packages` directory.

[image]

To fix it, browse the package for `package-metadata.json` file, rename or delete the file before moving it to `Packages` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I found that simply remove the file `package-metadata.json` in your package folder will prevent Sublime Text delete your package folder under `Sublime Text\Packages` when restart. Please try.